# Speediest MYSQL structure for the following?

Tags: php, mysql

Currently storing  3 bits of information about an persons name.

```
name,nicename,searchname = ("Mr.Joe bloggs", "Mr-Joe-bloggs", "mrjoebloggs")
```

Name used for a user's display name, nicename for the url and searchname for realtime searching the database (so speed is a must, milliseconds matter!)

Currently one table holds all 3 fields, but how much more effient would it be to store each field in a seperate table?and relate everything by id?

or would that just waste extra selects relating them to one another? DB will have over 100m records.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on keeping those three fields, you'd be creating a one-to-one relationship with every piece of data. It would make sense to keep them all in the same row.

However, you might find it better to only store the name. When you need the "nice name", you can use a regex to replace periods and space (and other characters) with hyphens (or remove them). When a user searches for "mr joe bloggs", you can make a simple searching algorithm by dividing up the three words and using the LIKE clause.

Comment: Unfortunately with my use I don't think I could get away with only storing the name, for instance when people type in mysite.com/mr-joe-bloggs it'll use that as the key to grab all related info. With the searchname (it will be auto suggest like google) using java to strip the nonalphanum chars and then searching against the db to match with the searchname so it will return a match if someone types in either "mr. j  b" or "mr j b"

Comment: If you want people to type in URLs without an ID like that, and your table's going to have millions of rows, I'd agree with keeping the nicename field. There are some string manipulation functions in MySQL that could water down the normal name into a "nice name" at SQL level; but with that many records, that would cause quite a slowdown.

I believe you could still benefit from using the LIKE clause. If somebody types "j", "jo", or "joe bl", and you use LIKE against the real name, the database will return that record -- without having to specify an independent field for it.